# XPATH issue. Not able to read parts of html

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I need to able to click on a link (I am using Selenium and Java). I am searching the link using xpath but for some reason I am not getting most of the webpage, just a bunch of white spaces. In the image you can see the highlighted link I am looking for.

I tried:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='titre_1']/a")).getText()); 
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='li-7']/div/a")).getText());
```

I get: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

If I do:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*")).getText());
```

I only get a few elements from the page and bunch of white spaces. What could be wrong?

Please help. I couldn't fit in the entire html source to show you. I hope that's ok.

[html source pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdwqW.png)

Comment: Can you check if it is inside an iframe or not?

Comment: I see there is an iframe outside of the link I am looking for. How do I switch to it? Thanks :)

Comment: It has an iframe id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the element is inside an iframe, you can get it by switching to iframe then call findElement. See code below:

```
WebElement iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_the_iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
```

Then you can find the element with your xpath:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='titre_1']/a")).getText());
```